# What is the windows cmd prompt command to -> List 'n' file names in console from a directory having 100 files

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, prompt

I have a directory having 100 .txt files. I need windows command ( Unix equivalent : head cmd) to list, say only 10 files in my console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Powershell**

**To get the list of files use the below:**

Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -first 2

**Also to get any specific data use the *Select***

Example:

Get-ChildItem |Select-Object Name | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object
-first 2